# Formal definition of Wall Shear Stress (WSS)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain, biophysics

I am looking for the formal definition of the scalar wall shear stress for an arbitrary fluid in 3D. Here, I hope to find a definition that allows both positive and negative scalar values.

My intuition tells me that considering

$\tau = \frac{1}{2}\mu\left[(\nabla \vec{u} + (\nabla \vec{u})^T\right]$

as the shear stress tensor, the wall shear stress should be something like:

$\tau_w =  (\tau\cdot\vec{n})\cdot \vec{t}_1 + (\tau\cdot\vec{n})\cdot \vec{t}_2$

Where $\vec{t}_i$ are the orthogonal surface tangentials and $\vec{n}$ the normal pointing into the wall.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check with a professor gave me the answer. Indeed the wall shear stress is calculated by:

$$\tau_w = \vec t\cdot \tau \cdot \vec n$$

where $\vec t$ is the sum of surface tangentials of the wall.